# Hyperlinks in bibliography fields in context mkiv

Tags: bibliographies, context

How to make some bibliography fields in context mkiv active hyperlinks to external resources? I'm using the new bibliography subsystem with style apa.

Answer (score 2):

Just enable links using `\setupinteraction[state=start]`.  Of course you have provide some `doi` or `url` field.

```
\startbuffer[biblio]
@article{FEAST,
  title = {Density-matrix-based algorithm for solving eigenvalue problems},
  author = {Polizzi, Eric},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. B},
  volume = {79},
  issue = {11},
  pages = {115112},
  numpages = {6},
  year = {2009},
  month = {Mar},
  publisher = {American Physical Society},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevB.79.115112},
  url = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevB.79.115112}
}
\stopbuffer

\setupinteraction[state=start]
\usebtxdataset[biblio.buffer]
\usebtxdefinitions[apa]

\starttext
\citation[FEAST]
\placelistofpublications
\stoptext
```

[image]